# How to transfer items from Digital miner to ME Computers using tesseracts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I'm trying to copy the yogscast series "Hole Diggers"; how can I transfer items from a digital miner that is located in a different dimension into my ME Storage that is located in the original dimension using tesseracts. I tried using ME Export busses and buildcraft pipes but nothing seems to work. An other thing that I attempted was rewatching videos where they mess with the digital miner but they don't show how they managed to do it(Or I'm just retarded...). I can easily power the digital miner with a tesseract easily. I'm fairly new to tekkit and didn't understand a single thing when I did my own research... Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Make sure the digital miner and you ME system are chunkloaded.  Use a chest next to the receiving tesseract and use an ME Import Bus (ME Export is the other direction.  Taking something from the ME System and putting in an inventory).

There are many problems which can issues with miner setups:
- Is the tesseract at the digital miner configure correctly?  Make sure its sending items and receiving power. Make sure the redstone control is set to Low if you aren't using a lever anywhere near the tesseract, and Disabled if you are.
- Is the receiving tesseract configured properly?  Make sure its sending power and receiving items.  Check redstone control settings.  Put a chest next to the tesseract to make sure items are passing through.  Put an ME **Import** bus on that chest.  You may need to upgrade the speed on the import bus to make sure it keeps up with the digital miner.
- Is both your ME system and digital miner chunkloaded?  If either of them is not, whichever area you are not in will not do anything.  Either not send power or not receive power.

Comment: Honestly, the inverted export/import nonsense is kinda annoying....

Comment: Its a common UI problem.  From what perspective are terms derived?  For ME its from the perspective of the ME system.  But players are often viewing things from the perspective of inventories.  Either theirs or the chests they deposit things in.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need your tesseract's chunks need to be loaded. There might be a chunk loader in your tekkit modpack but you may want to take a look at vanilla chunk loaders on youtube.

Comment: I have two actually, one near the computer and one near the digital miner